# .htaccess DirectoryIndex /subfolder/index.php seems to manage links in a funny way

Tags: php, .htaccess, directoryindex

- I have the default myIndex.php in a subfolder of public_html.
- I added a file .htaccess in public_html.
- I added DirectoryIndex /subfolder/myIndex.php in it.

myIndex.php contains links and includes.
Includes seems to work but links dont: no images and no css but menu.php is included. Links in menu.php dont work either.

If I

- change .htaccess to DirectoryIndex index.php,
- create a file index.php in public_html,
- and put a link to "./subfolder/myIndex.php" in it

  everything works fine.

I dont understand what happens here.

Comment: put `var_dump(getcwd())` into your `myIndex.php`, and things will become clear. you're probably using relative paths, and they're relative to something other than what you think they are.

Comment: Links and other client side stuff like images or referencing external js/css files are relative to what the browser sees as the url. If you are loading the url `http://example.com/subfolder/myIndex.php` then all the links are relative to `/subfolder/` regardless of where they exist on disk. The browser doesn't know that you are including a file in php 3 directories up or wherever. The browser just sees a link to `./subfolder/another.php` on the file `/subfolder/myIndex.php` and assumes that `.` refers to `/subfolder/`. The fix is to use absolute urls for everything with leading `/`.

Comment: @Marc B the result I get is string(**) "/home2/username/public_html/subfolder/" and relative paths are set for this location. You are right but relative to what??

Comment: @Jonathan ok the url does not show subfolder/myIndex.php (why?)

Comment: The url should show whatever you put in the link. If you are using relative urls (`pageName.php` or `./pageName.php`) then it is relative to the page that the browser loaded, not where the file exists on disk. If you open the page `/sub/page.php` in the browser with a link to `./sub/test.php` really points to `/sub/sub/test.php`.

Comment: "Includes seems to work but links dont: no images and no css" - Includes (assuming PHP) are server-side, whilst images and CSS are linked client-side. It is your _relative_ client-side links that are the problem (as already mentioned). "the url does not show subfolder/myIndex.php (why?)" - `DirectoryIndex` returns the document _transparently_ (essentially an internal rewrite), it's not an external redirect (which you are essentially doing in the second example). In Apache 2.3.14+ you can force directory index to _redirect_, but this is probably not what you want to do. (?)

Answer (score 1):

[`DirectoryIndex`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryindex) determines what to do, when a client requests a directory. If you have

```
DirectoryIndex /subfolder/myIndex.php
```

then exactly this script will be executed every time the client requests a directory, no matter where this directory is, e.g. `/anotherfolder/` or `/static/`.
But when you have

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
```

instead, Apache looks for an `index.php` in the requested directory, e.g. `/anotherfolder/index.php` or `/static/index.php`.